# Remote Event Receiver on Project Online

Tags: project-server, remote-event-receiver, project-online

I am using a simple Provider-Hosted app containing Remote Event Receiver. The event receiver triggers when you create a sub site. It adds some lists on the newly created sub site.

I have deployed it to an Project Online Site Collection (PWA). When I create a sub site directly from the "create sub site" link it works. However when I use "Create a new project" link, it does not add my lists. It seem it doesn't work if you create a project by using "Create project" link. Any idea? I appreciate any kind of advice.

Comment: How is it registered?  Maybe it's registered to a specific site template and not all site templates trigger it?

Comment: It is registered to all site templates. both type of sub sites that are created in both way have same site template (PROJECTSITE#0).

Comment: Try to determine if the remote event receiver is being invoked.  What I do is place a try/catch around the entire processing block and have the catch block insert into a custom list on my site so I can get the error message being thrown.  You should also insert debugging statements ("RER entry") and similar comments at steps in the event receiver to see how far it's getting before failing (assuming it's being invoked -- put one right on the first line of the RER to see if it gets logged).

Comment: Thank you Dave, I will test and put a try/Catch block around my code and let you know.